# Include licenses of Maven dependencies

Tags: maven

Let's say you write a microservice, which includes (API) libraries as Maven dependencies (in compile scope). Then you will only *include* them in your project; you don't *modify* them.
Additionally you want to share your application only as source code; not in binary form or the like.

In this case, you do **not** *modify* and/or *redestribute* code of the dependencies.

So: Do you need to include licenses for these dependencies?
Do you need to include licences of dependencies, that aren't modified nor redestributed but only referenced by your application?

Comment: AFAIK I would ask this question on the Open Source StackExchange site.

Comment: Thanks. I've created the same question there: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/11390/include-licenses-of-maven-dependencies.

I'll update this Stackoverflow question as soon as I know more.